# MS Project VSTO 2010 and Windows 8

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsto, ms-project

I have written a MS Project addin using Visual Studio 2010 and the VSTO that ships with it. I am testing this with Project 2013.

The addin seems to work fine with Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2.

However, under Windows 8 and 8.1, the addin behaves oddly. Specifically:
1) The addin crashes randomly. The solution I found was to run Project 2013 as Administrator (by right-clicking and selecting "Run as Administrator"). This is strange, since I am already logged into Window as an admin!

2) It looks as though some features in the addin is disabled?

Is this something that people have seen before, and if yes, what is the solution>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. When I don't "Run as Admin", the application is running with reduced privilege. I was under the wrong impression that running apps, while logged in as admin, would make the app run with full privilege.

As far as why "Run as Admin" is needed in Windows 8 and not before, I am guessing that the reduced privilege mode in Win 8 is more restrictive than in previous versions.